# Add/List/Edit paragraphs while add/edit node

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I have installed paragraph module.

I have paragraph called Address contains relevant info.

It is attached to node.

Per page/article I have more than 100 address. If I use default Paragraph Classic view mode then page is going to be too huge.

What will be alternate solution?

Should be there List and Add button. Add/Edit/List will open in Modal Widget?

Need to use Entity browser and Paragraph Views.

Comment: Use the paragraphs experimental widget, despite its name it is the current, recommended one. Then create a special display mode for the paragraphs in collapsed state.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the [Paragraphs Collapsible](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_collapsible) module for a project with a big list of paragraphs to a node, and it works quite fine.

> Improves the Paragraphs widget by applying CSS tweaks and collapsible feature

Comment: Hi @AjitS, I already know this module. But we above requirement.

Comment: @Julia How about using the https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group module and have your paragraph field display in a collapsible fieldset or a horizontal tab.

Comment: Nope. We need to use Entity Browser and Views. So there will be 2 buttons Add Address and View address. Add address will open form in Modal and View address will show all listing of address if exists with edit and remove button.

Comment: @Julia I take it that you would've tried the https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_browser already?

Comment: Tried. But not able to achieve what I needed.